# Class.GetType() : Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, shared

I hope this is not a duplicate, here's a simplified sample of my code :

```
Public Class ClassUsingFriendClassComparerCustomCollection
  ' Blah blah members blah blah methods
  Private collection As ArrayList
  Public Sub sort() _
    Implements FNUICollection.sort
    Me.collection.Sort(New ComparerCustomCollection)
  End Sub
End Class

Friend Class ComparerCustomCollection
Implements IComparer
  Public Enum StuffCases
    GoForStuff
    GoForOtherStuff
  End Enum

  Private Function getCase(type as System.Type) As StuffCases
    ' Blah blah returns StuffCases value
  End Function

  Private Function relevantFunction(x as ACustomObject) as Boolean
  ' Select Case Me.getCase(ACustomObject.GetType()) ' Fails :(
    Select Case Me.getCase(Case x.GetType())        ' Works :)
      Case GoForStuff
        Me.doSomeStuffWith(x)
      Case GoForOtherStuff
        Me.doSomeOtherStuffWith(x)
    End Select
  End Function
End Class
```

I can't figure out why the commented line fails... Visual Studio reports :

> Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference in VB.net

Did I miss an obvious thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `ACustomObject` is a type and `x` is an object of that type. `Type.GetType()`. In your case possible ways to use this will be like the following:

```
x.GetType()
```

Or

```
Type.GetType("ACustomObject")
```